# Error with loadHtml on curled HTML

Tags: php, html, curl, domdocument

I have a script, where I am using curl to load webpage of a google play game.

Next, I am trying to extract the src of the `<img>` whose class is `"cover-image"`

Here's my script

```
<?php

$url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.castleclash";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$srcs = array();
$result = $xp->query("//img[@class='cover-image']/@src");
foreach($result as $attr) 
{
    echo $attr->value. "<br/>";
}

?>
```

The problem is that, if I am doing this code `echo $data;`

Then the whole html is displayed and i can get the src of cover-image

but when i am commenting out . i.e. removing the `echo $data;`, the code shows blank webpage with no data.

how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could directly load it into `->loadHTMLFile()`. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.castleclash');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src = $xp->query("//img[@class='cover-image']/@src");
foreach($image_src as $attr) {
    echo $attr->value. "<br/>";
}
```